# Debugging Android app after release

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

I am working on some fixes to an app already in the store. The app uses an expansion file. I have created a new version of the app and uploaded the apk and the associated expansion file. When I try to run the app from eclipse, the app starts up, but then the download of the expansion file fails with the message: "Download failed because you may not have purchased this app." Obviously I have NOT purchased the app, I am developing it! So how do I get this to work?

Comment: did it work before you upgraded to the new version? I think the easiest solution is just to buy it on the market...

Answer (score 3):

Since I don't know the code that is in your app I would like to provide you with some pointers to help you to find your answer:

- Have you updated the versionCode in your AndroidManifest.xml?
- Did you update the versionCode in your application that is used to get the expansion file(s)?
- Have you waited for around an hour after uploading the new .apk and new expansion files? It took me around an hour every time I had to upload a new .apk and/or expansion file before it was available to me.
- Have you uninstalled the application before trying to test out your new expansion file? With the provided Libraries a database will be used to store some information (like file size). An install of the application on top of an existing one might not remove the information from this database.

See picture below for next pointers:

- I assume you are using it but just to check, did you use the right "Public key"?
- Have you added the e-mail address at the "Test Accounts" section. This would be the e-mail address of the account on the device you are testing the expansion files with.
- Have you set the "License Test Response" to a response that suits your needs?

[image: Play store publisher account profile page]

If these pointers don't help you out I might need some more information about what you have tried etc. in order for me to help you.

Comment: +1: The expansion files downloader library uses the Google Play LVL for verification so you need to make sure your device is properly matching up as a test account.

Comment: License Test Response: LICENSED saved my day!

Answer (score 1):

Yes but now approach has been changed a bit. each and every application has key,

this error comes basically for few reasons, make sure :

1. you are logged in from your test acoount into your device.
2. key are same in your code as well.
3. you have mentioned the size of expansion file in code correctly in bytes.
4. after uploading wait for 3-4 hours, then it will start downloading instantly it does not work.