# "Download failed because you may not have purchased this app" when trying to debug

Tags: android, air, air-native-extension

I'm developing an Air app that uses an ANE to get the .obb files, everything works ok, however I'm getting (I think) an error, and I need to debug the app to see what's happening.

However, I can't debug because I get that message the moment the ANE tries to unzip the .obb file.

Any ideas what could be happening?.

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't know the code that is in your app I would like to provide you with some pointers to help you to find your answer:

- Have you updated the versionCode in your AndroidManifest.xml?
- Did you update the versionCode in your application that is used to
  get the expansion file(s)?
- Have you waited for around an hour after uploading the new .apk and
  new expansion files? It took me around an hour every time I had to
  upload a new .apk and/or expansion file before it was available to
  me.
- Have you uninstalled the application before trying to test out your
  new expansion file? With the provided Libraries a database will be
  used to store some information (like file size). An install of the
  application on top of an existing one might not remove the
  information from this database.

See picture below for next pointers:[image: Public key]

- I assume you are using it but just to check, did you use the right
  "Public key"? (In App's Services and APIs section)
  [image]
  [image]
- Have you added the e-mail address at the "Test Accounts" section.
  This would be the e-mail address of the account on the device you
  are testing the expansion files with. (In General Setting section and App's APK section)
- Have you set the "License Test Response" to a response that suits
  your needs? Play store publisher account profile page? (In General Setting section)

If these pointers don't help you out I might need some more information about what you have tried etc. in order for me to help you.
[Updated from this source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13636246/2810231)